# Getting 403 forbidden error while retrieving locations from quickblox

Tags: swift, quickblox

I am getting status as 403 forbidden when I use to retrieve locations,If i am sending location they are successfully sent. Here is my code what i am implementing

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        QBChat.instance().delegate = self

        user.login = uname
        user.password = pass

        QBRequest.logInWithUserLogin(uname, password: pass, successBlock: nil, errorBlock: nil)


        QBRequest.userWithLogin(uname, successBlock: { (response: QBResponse!,user: QBUUser!) in

            self.userDetails = user as QBUUser

            }, errorBlock: { (response: QBResponse!) in
                println(response.error)
        })
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
 @IBAction func getLocationTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

        QBRequest.geoDataWithId(self.userDetails!.ID, successBlock: { (response: QBResponse!,geoData: QBLGeoData!) in

            println("GeoData: \(geoData)")

            }, errorBlock: nil)
    }
```

and this is my error log.

> QuickBloxChat[2332:33100] Request headers: {
>       "Content-Type" = "application/json";
>       "QB-SDK" = "iOS 2.1";
>       "QB-Token" = 14f4ec467c5d9f00eb938529962366938042b05a;
>       "QuickBlox-REST-API-Version" = "0.1.1"; } 2015-10-03 11:56:26.143 QuickBloxChat[2332:33100] Response headers: {
>       "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
>       "Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
>       Connection = "keep-alive";
>       "Content-Length" = 24;
>       "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
>       Date = "Sat, 03 Oct 2015 06:26:25 GMT";
>       "QB-Token-ExpirationDate" = "2015-10-03 08:26:14 UTC";
>       "QuickBlox-REST-API-Version" = "0.1.1";
>       Server = "nginx/1.6.2";
>       Status = "403 Forbidden";
>       "X-Rack-Cache" = miss;
>       "X-Request-Id" = 9ef416cd199c9c8749dd85ce4a8d146b;
>       "X-Runtime" = "0.016744";
>       "X-UA-Compatible" = "IE=Edge,chrome=1"; }

I tried out login before getGeoDataWithID method but it doesn't work.
Please help me to get out of it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please use Custom Objects http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-customObjects-ios

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you pass a user's ID instead of some ID of geodata object

```
QBRequest.geoDataWithId(self.userDetails!.ID
```